# Adding square brackets [ ] to every .json file in the directory

Tags: json, powershell, automation

I have a bunch of separate .json files in one folder. Like this:

```
P50_00001.json
P50_00002.json
P50_00003.json
P50_00004.json
P50_00005.json....
```

Lots of them.

If you open them - they all look like this:

```json
{
"Participant_id":  "P50_00001",
"no_of_people":  "Single",
"apparent_gender":  "M",
"geographic_location":  "JPN",
"ethnicity":  "Japanese",
"capture_device_used":  "iOS14",
"camera_orientation":  "Portrait",
"camera_position":  "Frontal View",
"Indoors_Outdoors_env":  "Outdoors",
"lighting_condition":  "Medium",
"Occluded":  "None",
"scene_category":  "Nature",
"camera_movement":  "Still",
"action":  "No action",
"Indoors_Outdoors_in_moving_car_or_train":  "Outdoors",
"daytime_nighttime":  "daytime"
}
```

I need them to have square brackets in the beginning and the end:

```json
[
    {
    "Participant_id":  "P50_00001",
    "no_of_people":  "Single",
    "apparent_gender":  "M",
    "geographic_location":  "JPN",
    "ethnicity":  "Japanese",
    "capture_device_used":  "iOS14",
    "camera_orientation":  "Portrait",
    "camera_position":  "Frontal View",
    "Indoors_Outdoors_env":  "Outdoors",
    "lighting_condition":  "Medium",
    "Occluded":  "None",
    "scene_category":  "Nature",
    "camera_movement":  "Still",
    "action":  "No action",
    "Indoors_Outdoors_in_moving_car_or_train":  "Outdoors",
    "daytime_nighttime":  "daytime"
    }
]
```

How can I batch-add square brackets to all the .json files in one directory at once?

Comment: Why was this question closed when it's very clear what it's asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **PowerShell** solution:

For simplicity and speed, you can do *plain-text* processing:

```bash
# Defaults to the current dir; add -LiteralPath $yourDir as needed.
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.json -PipelineVariable file |
  ForEach-Object {
    "[`n" + ($_ | Get-Content -Raw) + "]" # Enclose existing content in [ ... ]
  } | 
  Set-Content -Encoding utf8 -LiteralPath { $file.FullName } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#-whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

Note the use of `-Encoding utf8` to control the output encoding; adjust as needed (the input encoding is not guaranteed to be preserved so omitting `-Encoding` will give you [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content)'s *default* encoding, which is ANSI in *Windows PowerShell*, and BOM-less UTF-8 in *PowerShell (Core)*).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using PowerShell:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem | Where Name -Like "*.json"
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $value = Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json
    $value = ,@($value)
    $value | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content $file
}
```

Note the comma before the `@($value)`. This is needed to get PowerShell to add a superfluous layer of list. Otherwise, single-item lists are dissolved into their item immediately.

Comment: My point is that SO is a peer to peer forum where users ask other users for help with **their self written code**. You showed no effort at all of trying to solve your problem by yourself in the first place. ;-)

Comment: @Olaf, I get the point, but my feeling is that if the question is clearly defined and potentially of _general_ interest, it's still worth answering. Multiple language tags aren't great either, but can sometimes lead to interesting contrasts between solution attempts in different languages.

Comment: This works (with the sample input), but I have a few suggestions: `Get-ChildItem | Where Name -Like "*.json"` -> `Get-ChildItem -Filter *.json`. `Get-Content $file | ConvertFrom-Json` -> `Get-Content -Raw $file | ConvertFrom-Json` (`-Raw` greatly speeds up reading). Omit `$value = ,@($value)` and use  `ConvertTo-Json @($value) -Depth 100 | Set-Content $file` instead - this bypasses the array-enumeration problem in the pipeline, and `-Depth 100` supports JSON data that is nested up to 100 levels without truncation (the default depth is 2, which is often exceeded in practice).

Comment: @Olaf Ok, I understand. Do you mean I didn't provide any solution in my initial post?
Like... Would it make more sense if I chose 1 language (Powershell for example)? Then tried to write a code, and asked for advice on why I can't get it to work instead of tagging every single language I have access to. It's just that it doesn't make any difference for me which way should it be done. Might as well be some sort of text processor or something.

Comment: @gfx2000 That would be considered as proper approach. Since it is a fairly simple task you could have tried to get this task done by yourself in the first place. And if you get stuck on the way you are very welcome to come here and ask for help. This way now someone did it for you.  ;-)

Comment: @gfx2000, there is no requirement to add code to your question. However, there is a requirement to do some research before posting a question. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)